# Character encoding and code cleaning...help pls

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

i am new of srackoverflow and i have a problem that i hope u guys can help me fix, since i broke my arm i need to get a faster way to copy and paste emails template into a email editor (in Siebel)...but so far i am having trouble because the html page i "wrote' is quite messy (i'm not good at it, i just take parts here and there and try to make them working together).
My biggest issue is that when i past the template in to the siebel email editor, all the character with axcent they come out wrong (like Ã² or Ã¬ ...and many other)

can smone pls help me in fixing the code properly??

I know that the codedon't work properly on firefox but i only need it to work on Ie (and apparently work) and most of all i need it working properly on siebel (automotive).

heres thesupermessy code

```
    <!-- CSS : AddOns - WorldA -->
    <!--<link rel="alternate stylesheet" title="styleA" type="text/css" media="all" 

href="core/css/D_worldA.css" />-->
<!-- JavaScript : Librarys: jQuery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://flash.nissan.it/core/lib/jQuery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript : Librarys: swfObject-->
    <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://flash.nissan.it/core/lib/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://flash.nissan.it/flash/devenv/deploy/js/swfaddress.js"></script>

<!-- JavaScript : Include and embedded versions-->

    <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://flash.nissan.it/core/scripts/document.ready.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://flash.nissan.it/core/scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        // <![CDATA[
         function resizeHeader(val){
         var flashHeader = document.getElementById('B_MediaNavigationLevel1');
         flashHeader.style.height=val+'px';
         var flashObject = document.getElementById('shell_header');
         flashObject.style.height=val+'px';
         }
         function resizeFooter(val){
         var flashFooter = document.getElementById('B_MediaNavigationLevel2');
         flashFooter.style.height=val+'px';
         var flashFooterObject = document.getElementById('shell_footer');
         flashFooterObject.style.height=val+'px';
         }
         // ]]>     
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // HEADER

               soHead = new SWFObject

("http://www.nissan.it/flash/devenv/deploy/shell/swf/shell.swf", "shell_header", "100%", "100%", 

"10.0.45.2", "#ffffff");
               soHead.useExpressInstall

('http://www.nissan.it/flash/devenv/deploy/shell/swf/expressinstall.swf');
               soHead.addVariable("confFile", "http://www.nissan.it/IT/it.-

shellconf.conf");
               soHead.addVariable("manifest", "http://www.nissan.it/IT/it.-

headerContent-Single-nointernal-trvheaderxml.xml");     
               soHead.addVariable("trvheader_resizeFunc", "resizeHeader" );
               soHead.addVariable("trvheader_emebed", "true" );
               soHead.addParam( "allowScriptAccess", "always" );
               soHead.addVariable("verbose", "false" );
               soHead.addVariable("fps", "false" );
               soHead.addVariable("trv_header_selected_nodeid", "glossary" );
               soHead.addParam( "wmode", "transparent" );



        // FOOTER
               soFoot = new SWFObject

("http://www.nissan.it/flash/devenv/deploy/shell/swf/shell.swf", "shell_footer", "100%", "100%", "10.0.45.2", "#ffffff");
               soFoot.useExpressInstall

('http://www.nissan.it/flash/devenv/deploy/shell/swf/expressinstall.swf');
               soFoot.addVariable("confFile", "http://www.nissan.it/IT/it.-

shellconf.conf" );
               soFoot.addVariable("manifest", 

"http://www.nissan.it/IT/it/glossary.-trvbottomNavxml.xml");
               soFoot.addVariable("trvfooter_resizeFunc", "resizeFooter" );
               soFoot.addParam( "allowScriptAccess", "always" );
               soFoot.addVariable("trvfooter_emebed", "true" );
               soFoot.addVariable("verbose", "false" );
               soFoot.addVariable("fps", "false" );
               soFoot.addParam( "wmode", "transparent" );      


               soHead.write( "B_MediaNavigationLevel1" );
               soFoot.write( "B_MediaNavigationLevel2" );

        }); 

    </script>

<!--  trackingHtmlContent -->


</head><body marginheight="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" leftmargin="0" class="body">

    <div id="theDocument">



<div id="A_body">
<div class="topDecoration"></div>
<div class="middleDecoration">

<div id="B_content" class="glossaryDisplay">
        <!-- component zone 2 -->



<div class="stdDisplay">
            <!-- component zone 3-->






<Script Language=JavaScript>

function copyToClipboard(ID){

ctrlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
ctrlRange.add(document.all(ID));
ctrlRange.execCommand("Copy");
}

</Script>



<style type="text/css">



#coolmenu a{
font: bold 13px Verdana;
padding: 5px;
padding-left: 4px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

html>body #coolmenu a{ /*Non IE rule*/
width: auto;
}

#coolmenu a:hover{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

</style>



<div id="coolmenu">




<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><ol class="descriptionList">
      <li class="openDefault" ><a href="#templ1" title="Concessionario Autorizzato">Concessionario Aut.</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ2" title="Centro Assistenza Fiducia">Centro Assistenza 

        Fiducia</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ3" title="CETOC">CETOC</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ4" title="Dati Mancanti">Dati Mancanti</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ5" title="Contatti Nissan Italia">Contatti Nissan Italia</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ6" title="Inviare Richiesta Scritta Roma">Inviare Richiesta Scritta Roma </a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ7" title="Richiesta Info+Link">Richiesta Info+Link</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ8" title="Libretto uso/manutenzione o garanzia">Libretto 

        uso/manutenzione o garanzia</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ9" title="Elenco Concessionari GT-R">Elenco Concessionari GT-

        R</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ10" title="Infiniti: Info Request+link">Infiniti: Info Request

        +link</a></li>
      <li  ><a href="#templ11" title="Qashqai Tempi di attesa">Qashqai Tempi di attesa</a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ12" title="SCONTI CATEGORIE SPECIALI - LEGGE 104 ETC">Sconti categorie speciali - legge 104 etc.</a></li>
    </ol></td>
    <td><ol class="descriptionList">
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ13" title="DISPONIBILITÁ VEICOLI PRESSO CONCESSIONARI">Disponibilita veicoli presso cocessionari </a></li>
      <!-- "Access description from" -->
      <li  ><a href="#templ14" title="RISORSE UMANE – CURRICULUM ETC.">Risorse umane -cv - etc.</a></li>

      <li  ><a href="#templ15" title="RECLAMO: SEGNALAZIONE E CODICE">Reclamo: segnalazione e codice</a></li>
    </ol></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<!-- "Access description from" -->


</ol>
</div>

<div class="glossaryContainer">
<div class="glossaryTab" id="templ1">Concessionario Autorizzato <br> <input type=button value='Copy Table To Clipboard' onClick="copyToClipboard('thisTable')"> 

<table id='thisTable' class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr id=>
<td id="t1" width=852>email template in here</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<a class="anchorLink" href="#A_body">Torna sù</a>
        </div>
        <!-- component zone 4 (title area)-->   


    </div>
    <!-- MAIN DATA CONTAINER  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

</div>  

</div>
</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

Comment: See [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Jared: Code Review is not for problems with functionality of the code, it's for problems with style/design of the code.

Comment: @BalusC - Fair enough. I anticipate if the code is "cleaned up", it will probably work, which is what I imagined CR is for, but I can't ever get these satellite SE site's purposes straight. `:)`

Comment: @Jarred: Okay, CR is for *working* code. This code doesn't work :)

Comment: @Jarred: i don'y know what u mean for doesn't work....in my ie it work (not on ff, but i need it only on ie bcause is for personal use). The only  (and also very important) thinks that does no work is the carachter with accent, or better, it works on Ie but do not work when i paste the copied content into the siebel email editor (i get strange carhacters instead of accent)...dunno if u get what i mean.  anyway thx 4 the help guys

Comment: @iblazevic: i have tried the string that u write but wasn't working as well. I should put that string in top of  the page or inside the table i want to copy?? (i will try both on monday)....ty

Comment: @BalusC - See the second comment above this one from the OP. Maybe *working* and *broken* is potentially subjective, especially in view of the developers feelings. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

You should put this string in "head" tag where meta usually goes

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```